# Target class [LoginAdminController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i have this error when user return from login to home page i can't understand what is it i am doing MultiAuth in laravel 5 and also help me if i can use login function and other registration function that is already available for users table i have no idea how to do that with already written functions

this my route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group([
    'prefix' => config('admin.prefix'),
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
],function(){
    Route::get('login', 'LoginAdminController@formLogin')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginAdminController@login');

    
    Route::get('daftar', 'RegisterController@form')->name('admin.register');
    Route::post('daftar', 'RegisterController@simpan');

    });

    Route::middleware(['auth:admin'])->group(function(){
        Route::post('logout', 'LoginAdminController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
        Route::view('/', 'dashboard')->name('dashboard'); 
        Route::view('/post', 'data-post')->name('post')->middleware('can:role, "admin","editor"');
        Route::view('/admin', 'data-admin')->name('admin')->middleware('can:role, "admin"');
            
        });
```

this my LoginAdminControllers

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class LoginAdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin',['except'=>'logout']);
        
    }
    public function formlogin()
    {
        return view('login');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:admins',
            'password' => 'required',
            ]);
            if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials, $request->remember)){
                $request->session()->regenerate();
                return redirect()->intended(config ('admin.prefix'));
            }
            return back()->withErrors([
                'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
                ]);
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }            
}
```

Comment: Check if your controller is in the correct path. It should be in `app/Http/Controllers` (case sensitive). Also try doing a `composer dump-autoload` and see if that warns you about any naming issues